# Sticky Nav with Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I've made a nav with a sticky header that shrinks a little as you scroll

I'd like to have a large image above the nav so the user would have to scroll down, the nav will rise and eventually stick in place. I'm having trouble finding a tutorial.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
function myScroll()
{
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  var title = document.getElementById("title");
  var yPos = window.pageYOffset;
  var nav = document.getElementById("myNav")
  
  if(yPos > 300)
  {
    header.style.height = "80px";
    title.classList.add("shrink");
    nav.style.marginTop = "25px";
  }
  else
  {
    header.style.height = "150px";
    title.classList.remove("shrink");
    nav.style.marginTop = "90px";
  }
};


window.addEventListener("scroll", myScroll);
```

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

#header
{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}

#title
{
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: all .3s;
  float: left;
}

#title.shrink
{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

nav
{
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 90px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#content
{
  height: 2000px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 160px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="title">Animated Scroll</h1>
  
  <nav id="myNav">
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think your code appears to be having any difficulty and you don't seem to need tutorials.

Comment: No the shrink is working fine, but above the header I want to have a large banner image.  so they'll have to scroll past the banner which will cause the nav to scroll up for a bit and then stick.  But I'm not sure on how to control where the nav sticks

Comment: Hm, just add a class or change the position to fixed through the js api once the relevant content is in the viewport. It really depends how big and where that image is gonna be.